# Adding user defined nodes to math NOAD

Tags: luatex

I'm trying to tag a math superscript using `mlist_to_hlist` callback. I imagine superscript noad like a `head` (or `list` having two noad lists `nucleus` and `sup`) where I can put my created noads. But I can't simply get to work `node.insert_before`or `node.insert_after` functions. 
I want to add user defined nodes (tags) surrounding all superscript and its parts like `nucleus` and `sup`. Desired result in output would look like this:

```
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.8572
...\hbox(7.1428+0.0)x5.03473, shifted 169.98264, direction TLT
....\whatsit0="pre_superscript"
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
.....\whatsit0="pre_nucleus"
.....\whatsit0="empty"
.....\whatsit0="post_nucleus"
....\hbox(3.01389+0.0)x5.03473, shifted -4.12892, direction TLT
.....\whatsit0="pre_sup"
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 x
.....\whatsit0="post_sup"
....\whatsit0="post_superscript"
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
```

Surrounding `..._nucleus` and `..._sup` tags can by out of the box too (if they don't influence the output). By now I'm getting only:

```
...\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.8572
...\hbox(7.1428+0.0)x5.03473, shifted 169.98264, direction TLT
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
.....\whatsit0="empty"
....\hbox(3.01389+0.0)x5.03473, shifted -4.12892, direction TLT
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/7 x
....\whatsit0="post_superscript"
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
```

Here is my MWE (math.lua):

```
local USER_MARK   = node.new("whatsit","user_defined")
USER_MARK.type    = 115   -- This means that value is a Lua string
USER_MARK.value   = "0"     -- anything

local function tag_superscript (h, d, p)
    for n in node.traverse(h) do
        if n.sup then

            if n.nucleus then 
                -- maybe its not nessesary, but there is no where 
                -- to stick "pre_nucleus" and "post_nucleus"
                if node.type(n.nucleus.id) == "sub_mlist" 
                   and not n.nucleus.head then
                    local submlist = node.new("sub_mlist")
                    local usermark = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                    usermark.value = "empty"
                    -- is it valid to create head like this?
                    submlist.head = usermark
                    n.nucleus.head = submlist.head
                end

                -- tagging superscript base (nucleus) 
                local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                A.value = "pre_nucleus"
                node.insert_before(n.nucleus, n.nucleus, A) -- what is proper head ????

                local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                B.value = "post_nucleus"
                node.insert_after(h, n.nucleus, B)

            end

            -- tagging sup begin and end
            local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            A.value = "pre_sup"
            node.insert_before(n.sup, n.sup, A)

            local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            B.value = "post_sup"
            node.insert_after(h, n.sup, B)

            -- tagging all superscript begin and end
            local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            A.value = "pre_superscript"
            node.insert_before(h, n, A)

            local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            B.value = "post_superscript"
            node.insert_after(h, n, B)    
        end
    end
    return node.mlist_to_hlist(h, d, p)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('mlist_to_hlist', tag_superscript, 'Tag superscript')
```

Tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\directlua{dofile("math.lua")}

\begin{document}
\loggingall
$$ {}^x $$
\end{document}
```

Empty superscript nucleus (`{}`) I did specially to see how the nodes list is treated. I tried various approaches `n.next`, `n.sup.head`, `n.sup.next` within `node.insert_before` and `node.insert_after` but I get errors about non existing noads or any effect.
Any advice or explanation about how appending to math NOAD works would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add multiple things in the nucleaus/sup, so you need the nucleus/sup to be a list. If it isn't, you can create a list with only one noad containing the original nucleus/sup as nucleus. Then you have a list, so you can use the head `n.nucleus.head`.

Another problem is your use of `insert_before`: `insert_before` and `insert_after` sometimes change the list head. They can not assign the new list head by themselves through, so they return the new list head.
This isn't a problem for you with `insert_after` because you never insert the first node in a list, but `insert_before` might be called with the head of the list. So assign the return value to the original list head.

I also added a `user_id` for you to identify your whatsit later on:

```
local USER_MARK   = node.new("whatsit","user_defined")
USER_MARK.user_id = luatexbase.new_whatsit'my_special_whatsit'
USER_MARK.type    = 115   -- This means that value is a Lua string
USER_MARK.value   = "0"     -- anything

local function tag_superscript (h, d, p)
    for n in node.traverse(h) do
        if n.sup then
            if n.nucleus then 
                -- maybe its not nessesary, but there is no where 
                -- to stick "pre_nucleus" and "post_nucleus"
                if node.type(n.nucleus.id) == "sub_mlist" 
                   and not n.nucleus.head then
                    local usermark = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                    usermark.value = "empty"
                    n.nucleus.head = usermark
                end

                if node.type(n.nucleus.id) ~= "sub_mlist" then
                  local sublist = node.new'sub_mlist'
                  local noad = node.new'noad'
                  noad.nucleus = n.nucleus
                  sublist.head = noad
                  n.nucleus = sublist
                end
                -- tagging superscript base (nucleus) 
                local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                A.value = "pre_nucleus"
                n.nucleus.head = node.insert_before(n.nucleus.head, n.nucleus.head, A)

                local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
                B.value = "post_nucleus"
                node.insert_after(n.nucleus.head, node.tail(n.nucleus.head), B)
            end
            -- tagging sup begin and end
            if node.type(n.sup.id) ~= "sub_mlist" then
              local sublist = node.new'sub_mlist'
              local noad = node.new'noad'
              noad.nucleus = n.sup
              sublist.head = noad
              n.sup = sublist
            end
            -- tagging superscript base (nucleus) 
            local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            A.value = "pre_sup"
            n.sup.head = node.insert_before(n.sup.head, n.sup.head, A)

            local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            B.value = "post_sup"
            node.insert_after(n.sup.head, node.tail(n.sup.head), B)

            -- tagging all superscript begin and end
            local A = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            A.value = "pre_superscript"
            h = node.insert_before(h, n, A)

            local B = node.copy(USER_MARK)
            B.value = "post_superscript"
            node.insert_after(h, n, B)    
        end
    end
    return node.mlist_to_hlist(h, d, p)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('mlist_to_hlist', tag_superscript, 'Tag superscript')
```

Another note: `node.traverse` does not recurse into sublists, so your code will ignore any superscript in a sublist, e.g. nested superscripts, fractions, ...

Comment: `\left...\right` constructions are also sublists.

Comment: Marcel,  perfect! Strange part was that sometimes don't need to assign a new head to `node.insert_before` but now I understood the concept.